# Is there a way to determine what service pack is on a computer that will not boot? The OS is XP 32 bit

Tags: windows-xp

I am working on a Dell Latitude E6500 that will not boot.  It states that the following file is missing "C:\Windows\System\Config\System".

Is there a way to determine what service pack is on a computer that will not boot?  The OS is XP 32 bit.

Comment: There is a registry key that defines the Service Pack being used... Have you tried to boot in Safe Mode? Have you tried to repair with the installation CD/DVD?

Answer (score 2):

No need to mount a registry file from the failed system, which is a bad idea anyway because mounting a hive modifies the file and can potentially cause more damage.

Simply check the version of the %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\ntdll.dll file.

Here is [a comprehensive table of version numbers](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/ntdll/history/index.htm).  The ones you're interested in are:

```
5.1.2600.0      Windows XP
5.1.2600.1106   Windows XP SP1
5.1.2600.2180   Windows XP SP2
5.1.2600.5512   Windows XP SP3
```

If you're using a non-Windows OS, getting to the version number might be tricky (but not as tricky or dangerous as mounting the registry)  The link above also lists modification dates and file sizes for each version.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: Hardly.  The PE file format is much simpler than a registry hive, and [there are cross-platform tools](https://www.google.com/search?q=inspect+pe+header+linux).  But the modification date and file size are even easier to check.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: If you forget to unload it, it'll be left marked as in-use and unusable.  [Here's one user who ran into this](http://www.pctools.com/forum/showthread.php?20286-Forgot-to-unload-hive-(WNT)).   And I have done it myself.

Comment: I'll debate that that post is from the beginning of Windows (2002 in comparison to the release date of 2001). Still, I got your point. My answer is still valid in case the ntdll.dll file is missing. Let's *sanitize* the comments as they are not really helping anyone but us.

Answer (score -1):

Regardless of whether you can or can not repair the underlying Windows installation, there exists a "hack" that allows to cheat Windows into thinking it is a SP3 when it is still SP2. There are some uses to this, but I won't delve in this.

As @BenVoigt warns, **accessing and changing the registry without proper precautions can damage the underlying installation**. So, **proceed with care**.

This is still useful in case something somewhere deletes the `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\ntdll.dll`, rendering @BenVoigt method useless.

Quoting from [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/tr-dojo/registry-hack-tricks-windows-xp-sp2-into-thinking-its-running-sp3/) the relevant parts:

> 1. Open the Registry Editor.
> 2. Navigate to the key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows
>
>    [image]
> 3. Double-click the DWORD value CSDVersion and change the value data from 200 to 300.
>
>    [image]
> 4. Click OK.
> 5. Close the Registry Editor. 6. Reboot the machine. The machine will now think that you’ve applied SP3 when you’re actually running Windows XP SP2.

This post from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954375.aspx), albeit cryptic, does give insight on the values CSDVersion accepts. Quoting:

> Note that, if you need to verify the version of an NT4 Service Pack prior to Service Pack 4, you should also query the following registry key to determine the SP level, as in this sample.
>
> HKLM\system\CurrentControlSet\control\windows\CSDVersion
>
> The values of CSDVersion will be 0x100 for Service Pack 1, 0x200 for Service Pack 2, and so forth.

Henceforth:

- Original - Doesn't have (or CSDVersion = 0)
- SP1 - CSDVersion = 0x100
- SP2 - CSDVersion = 0x200
- SP3 - CSDVersion = 0x300

Now, for the accessing the registry without booting. [Raymond.cc](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-edit-windows-registry-key-values-without-booting-in-windows/) suggests four different ways to access the registry without actually booting into Windows.

All of the methods require some sort of bootable device. I'll list the methods referred in the link.

- PC Regedit
- Hiren’s Boot CD ISO
- Lazesoft Recovery Suite Home
- UBCD4Win

All relevant download links are on the page mentioned before.

Comment: If it can be cheated, it obviously isn't reliable.

Comment: Who says the person checking the version is the same as the person who cheated?

Comment: If `ntdll.dll` is missing, check any of the other system DLLs.  If more than a couple of them are missing, you can't accurately describe it as a computer with Windows on it, and the answer to "Which version of XP?" becomes: NONE.

Comment: Also, it appears that you paid no attention to the question at all... you raise objections that the file I suggest checking *might* be missing, when we know for a fact that **the file your method relies on actually is missing/corrupted**.